# How can I run a server side code inside an <asp:button .../> tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters

In ASP.NET, in the client side I used a repetitive method to generate a table with data from a Database. For each entry, I have an asp button to delete each of the entries. Now, I have an issue when I need to pass, for each button it's ID from the database, and because it's an `<asp:button ... />`, I cannot run a server side code line with CommandArgument='<%=id %>' so I can put it's ID to each of the buttons. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a repeater, you can use like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="box">
            <%# Eval("name") %>  
            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Button>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

---C#------

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
...
((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)(e.CommandSource)).CommandArgument - is the id of current row
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use binding expression.

```
<%# Id %>
```

and call `Control.DataBind()` or `DataBind()` method from code-behind.